# How do I passing sqldatasource parameters using javascript

Tags: javascript, sqldatasource

I have sqldatasource which is type store procedure and I want to passing parameters into it but using javascript

> "
>           SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
>   SelectCommand="sp_GetEmployeeByRoleId">

Comment: Are you running JScrip in an ASP page? Please supply the rest of the code if so.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen a database connection directly established from javascript, I rather suspect it isn't possible.